# How do you setup a Nokia Apps development environment?

Tags: java, c++, nokia

Seems that Nokia Developers website isn't keen to give solid information on how to set up a basic programming environment for Nokia Apps.

I tried the Carbide C++ pathway once and couldn't even get the HelloWorld to compile & run. So my question is this: How do you setup Nokia Apps development and which platform to use? (C++, Java, QT?, QML)

My guess is that once this is done you just copy the .SIS or .SISX file to your phone and it should work there.

Answer (score 3):

The environment that you should use depends on the device platforms that you want to target, e.g. Java for S40, Qt for Symbian 3, etc. There is a [summary](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/) page on [Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/) which gives an overview.

I'm not too familiar with Java development for S40 but if you want to target S60 or S^3 then by far the easiest path is to download the most recent version of the Nokia Qt SDK (currently [1.1](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/Getting_started/)). This package contains the Qt Creator IDE, including debugging and deployment tools, and all of the platform components needed to develop Qt-based apps. There is also emulator support and the ability to use remote compiler services to cross-compile binaries for various different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

QT would probably be the easiest to get going. Not everyone like Symbian C++, and S40 is a very limited platform